# Particle Turbulence Effect in Babylon.js

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

Is there any way to implement a turbulence effect in a babylon.js Particle System? I know that its possible to use physics engines on mesh objects, but I've not seen any discussion of using them on a babylon particle system.

Might there be a way to bake a particle system as a .vdb and import it if real-time simulation is not an option?

Comment: Have you tried using the [noise texture perturbation](https://doc.babylonjs.com/babylon101/particles#noise-texture) for this kind of effect?

Comment: Yes, this was what I was looking for, thanks @DMGregory

Comment: If you solved your problem using this, would you like to write up your solution as an Answer below that can help other devs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a noise texture to "perturbate" the position of particles. The noise texture is used to apply changes in the direction of the particles.

```
   var noiseTexture = new BABYLON.NoiseProceduralTexture("perlin", 256, scene);
   noiseTexture.animationSpeedFactor = 5;
   noiseTexture.persistence = 2;
   noiseTexture.brightness = 0.5;
   noiseTexture.octaves = 2;

   particleSystem.noiseTexture = noiseTexture;
   particleSystem.noiseStrength = new BABYLON.Vector3(100, 100, 100);
```

Demo can be found here: https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#R1JWLA#3 -